# How to split the my flowfile content based on '\n'?

Tags: java, split, apache-nifi

i have try to create sample custom processor for read lines and made some changes in input lines then process into flowfile.

This is my code to read flowfile.

```
String inputRow;
session.read(flowFile, new InputStreamCallback() {
                @Override
                public void process(InputStream in) throws IOException {
                  inputRow = IOUtils.toString(in);
                }
            });
```

observed that code from below reference.

http://www.nifi.rocks/developing-a-custom-apache-nifi-processor-json/

After read lines i can't able split those lines based on LineFeed character.

upstream connection for my processor yields below my sample input.

**My Sample input line:**

```
No,Name,value
1,Si,21
2,LI,321
3,Ji,11
```

Above lines can able to stored in **"inputRow"**.

But i have using below code to split it based on '\n'.

```
String[] splits=inputRow.split("\n");
```

i have tried '\n' and '\r\n' to split those lines but it's not worked.

Any one please guide me to split those lines as below expected output.

```
splits[0]=No,Name,value
splits[1]=1,Si,21
splits[2]=2,LI,321
splits[3]=3,Ji,11
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is your input in `inputRow`? Is it `"No,Name,value\n1,Si,21\n2,LI,321\n3,Ji,11"`? If not. What is it exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer, you should be able to use a BufferedReader to read line-by-line. You should also avoid loading the entire contents of the flow file into memory whenever possible.

Imagine that this NiFi processor is processing 1GB CSV files and that there could be 2-3 files processed concurrently. If you read the whole flow file content into memory, you will hit out-of-memory if you have less than 3GB of heap allocated to the JVM. If you stream each file line-by-line you would only have 2-3 lines in memory at one time and would need very little overall memory.

The following snippet shows how you could read in a line, process it, and write it out, without ever having the whole content in memory:

```
flowFile = session.write(flowFile, new StreamCallback() {
            @Override
            public void process(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
                try (InputStreamReader inReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inReader);
                     OutputStreamWriter outWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
                     BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(outWriter)) {

                    String line = reader.readLine();
                    while (line != null) {
                        line = process(line);

                        writer.write(line);
                        writer.newLine();

                        line = reader.readLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex for splitting: `\\r?\\n`.

```
String[] splits = inputRow.split("\\r?\\n");
```

Comment: @UHBBRP Are you sure your linebreak is `\n`? If your using Java8, you can try `\R`, which will work for **any linebreak sequence**.

Answer (score 2):

Why pushing everything into a single string? Just read them line by line; and push those lines into a List right there:

```
List<String> inputRows = new ArrayList<>();
```

...

and within your callback you use a BufferedReader like this:

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   inputRows.add(line);
 }
```

Comment: Using a BufferedReader and reading line-by-line is definitely a good approach. In addition, NiFi supports a stream callback that has an input stream and an output stream, this way you can read a single line, process it, and write it to the outputstream, and never store all lines in memory at a single time.

Comment: Thanks ... but I am not sure if I get everything here: are you suggesting that a BufferedReader is OK, but that my solution to append all data to that central list is a bad idea? Where I don't see the big difference; as the initial input also reads **all** data into a single shot into a single string into memory ...

Comment: I upvoted your answer and am agreeing with your suggestion, and I am offering an additional improvement. Imagine that this NiFi processor is processing 1GB CSV files and that there could be 2-3 files processed concurrently. With the given approaches you will hit out of memory if you have less than 3GB of heap allocated to the JVM, where as if you were streaming each file line by line you would only every have 3 lines in memory at one time and would need very little overall memory.

Comment: And I realize the original code also read everything into memory, I am suggesting that should have been done with a stream callback as well.

Comment: OK; then I guessed what you meant - but I have to admit; I am kinda stuck right now ... so: feel free to edit my answer if you have a better way to solve the problem. I am always very grateful when other people add good content to my answers. Seriously.

Comment: @GhostCat It depends on what OP is trying to do with the content -- if they need the entire content in memory at once, then your solution is fine. If they are just performing a transformation or other streaming operation (which is frequent in NiFi), there is no reason to store *all* the contents on the heap at once, so rather than reading each line into a list, it would process in place and use an OutputStream callback to write back to flowfile content inline and drop that line from the heap.

Comment: @BryanBende (and Andy) ... very much appreciate your input ... had some upvotes going your way to say thank you - learned a bit about something new doing so!